# Telerik modal mvc Unable to get property 'scripts'

Tags: javascript, telerik, telerik-mvc

Using Telerik controls version 2012.1.214.340 with mvc 3. I want to open a modal window to an external page and thought it would be straight forward....but either it is not...or more likely I am not googling / reading the correct documentation.

I don't really want to load the content into a hidden div and then pop it modal later if the user chooses to do so.

I would prefer to just do it all in javascript / jquery and so my research led me to write this:

What I wrote thus far in javascript is:

```
var windowElement = $.telerik.window.create({
    title: "Test Modal",
    html: "<strong>Where am I</strong>",
    contentUrl: 'http://www.google.com',
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: true,
    scrollable: false,
    onClose: function () { }
     });
```

cshtml razor is:

```
@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
        .jQuery(false)
        .jQueryValidation(false)
        .DefaultGroup(grp => grp
            .Add("telerik.window.min.js")
            ))
        )
```

When I run the site I get this error on load of the page:

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'scripts' of undefined or null reference

and the debugger is on this line in the telerik.window.min.js

```
b.scripts.push("telerik.window.js")
```

Based upon the line it broke on I went looking for telerik.window.js and didn't find it in the project...huh? The previous owner didn't include that one file?

So I went to google code and found [this](https://raw.github.com/juanplopes/simple-telerik/master/telerik/Telerik.Web.Mvc/Scripts/telerik.window.js).

Created the file and added it as such and still I get the error...

So I think I am missing something else but not sure exactly what.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to manually include a telerik JS file, they should be loaded automatically  (as long as they are in a correct folder).
Do you have a folder **/Scripts/2012.1.214** with a lot of telerik.js file + jquery ?
Can you try again without adding that file to the DefaultGroup ?
But you'll have another problem, as I see you declare **jQuery(false)**. Was it done on purpose ? Because if you set it to false, and don't declare another jQuery file in the DefaultGroup, nothing will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, doing this worked for me:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Window()
    .Name("_placeholder")
    .Visible(false)
)
```

Including somewhere on the page a static window that will never be used - telerik seems to only include scripts when an control of that type is used.